# sql query - wrong result

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, one of them contains comments and the other the rating for each comment.
Here`s the query:

```
SELECT c.id,
       c.parent_id,
       c.name,
       c.body AS comment,
       c.user_id, 
       DATE_FORMAT( c.date_add, '%d %M %Y %H:%i') AS dt,
       c.deleted, 
       IFNULL( SUM( r.rate ), 0 ) AS rate
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(rating) AS rate, 
           comment_id AS comment_id
    FROM rating
    GROUP BY comment_id
) r ON c.id = r.comment_id;
```

Tables content:

```
table Comments:
id
40
41
42

table Rating:
comment_id  Rating
41            -1
42             1
```

The query should return:

```
id     Rating
41       -1
42        1
43        0
```

REturns:

```
id     Rating
41        2
```

Could you please somebody tell me where`s the mistake.

Comment: Is this mysql, or sql-server? They are different.

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: it`s mysql. Input - tables with comments and ratings, output - summed raitings for each comment.

Comment: You can improve the quality of your question by also including sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the below version?

```
SELECT c.id, 
       c.parent_id,
       c.name,
       c.body AS comment,
       c.user_id,
       DATE_FORMAT( c.date_add, '%d %M %Y %H:%i'),
       c.deleted,
       (SELECT SUM(rating) FROM rating r Where r.comment_id = c.id) AS rate
FROM comments AS c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `COUNT` here?

```
IFNULL( COUNT( r.rate ), 0 ) AS rate
```

It should probably be

```
IFNULL(r.rate, 0) AS rate
```

Your final query would be like:

```
SELECT c.*,
       IFNULL(r.rate, 0) AS rate
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(rating) AS rate, 
           comment_id AS comment_id
    FROM rating
    GROUP BY comment_id
) r ON c.id = r.comment_id;
```

However - you don't need a subquery. You can get the same result with

```
SELECT c.*,
       IFNULL(SUM(rating), 0) AS rate
FROM comments AS c
LEFT JOIN rating r ON c.id = r.comment_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/UIK19423

Comment: Thanks. Actually i used SUM, just tried COUNT and copied it by mistake. Corrected.